The regular expression for parsing Telegram usernames stops parsing valid usernames if there is an invalid username in the same line
I have one problem here, I have a regexp that extracts the username in Telegram links, starting from a simple "@" to username.t.me links

The problem is that if I enter @aaaa, @jfewewf, both usernames match correctly, but when I enter @aaaa, @jfewewf_, neither username matches, even though the script should match only username @aaaa (because the username on the right side is not valid)
Here is my regex:
(?:(?<!\S)@|(?:(?:https?://|)(?:t\.me|telegram\.(?:me|dog))/(?:c/|)|tg://resolve\?domain=)|(?=^(?!.*__)(?!.*_{2,})[a-z][a-z0-9_]{3,31}(?<!_)\.t\.me$))(?P<username>(?!.*__)(?!.*_$)(?!.*_{2,})[a-z][a-z0-9_]{3,31})(?P<subdomain>\.t\.me)?

You can test it at this link: https://regex101.com/r/JFF1S0/9
Please help me 
I've already tried almost everything, I don't know how to solve it at all.

what constitutes a valid username? could you provide the desired output for your sample data?

You expect multiple matches, BUT you are using .* in your restrictive negative lookaheads (e.g. (?!.*__)(?!.*_$)(?!.*_{2,})), so no wonder you do not get expected matches. Restrict the . inside these lookaheads to valid username chars.

@DuesserBaest, Usernames that begin or end with an underscore, those that begin with a number, those that contain two underscores in a row, those that consist only of numbers, those that contain symbols other than Latin letters, numbers, and underscores are considered invalid.
The only problem here is that due to one invalid username in one line, the valid username does not parse, as it was shown in the image

@WiktorStribiżew, So what should I change?

The dot........

To me it looks like you have lost control over your regex. It looks very convoluted. When building such a long pattern, better use comment-mode and indent conditions. See if this update of your pattern (regex101) helps. Regarding the lookaheads, you need to use a character set to not skip over whitespaces which seperates your items. This can be \S (non-whitespace) or more specific.

If your usernames only contain "word" chars, then you can default to \w. Here is your regex with \w. Here is BB's regex with \w.

@OkineaDev Without comments: (?<!\S)(?![^\s_]*_(?:$|\.|[^\s_]*_))(?:@|(?:https?://)?(?:t\.me|telegram\.(?:me|dog))/(?:c/)?|tg://resolve\?domain=|^(?=\S*\.t\.me$))(?P<username>[a-z]\w{3,31})(?P<subdomain>\.t\.me)?

@bobblebubble I've already refactored, fixed bugs and added comments - https://regex101.com/r/JFF1S0/22
This regex is now much clearer

@OkineaDev I see, that's clearer now! How about updating your answer, where you still use the problematic (?!.*...). Btw. In you new regex I think you can drop the (?!\w*_{2,}) directly after (?!\w*__) which is redundant (same check twice).

To do this, remove (?!.*_$) and add (?<!_)\b after [a-z][a-z0-9_]{3,31}
Here is the updated regular expression:
(?:(?<!\S)@|(?:(?:https?://|)(?:t\.me|telegram\.(?:me|dog))/(?:c/|)|tg://resolve\?domain=)|(?=^(?!.*__)(?!.*_{2,})[a-z][a-z0-9_]{3,31}(?<!_)\.t\.me$))(?P<username>(?!.*__)(?!.*_{2,})[a-z][a-z0-9_]{3,31}(?<!_)\b)(?P<subdomain>\.t\.me)?

https://regex101.com/r/JFF1S0/10
Original answer from Telegram chat:


This checks to the end of the line, so it finds the "_" at the end and does not take the entire line [1]


try https://regex101.com/r/C6FZER/1 [1]


im remove you (?!.*_$) and add (?<!_)\b after [a-z][a-z0-9_]{3,31} [3]


(?<!_)\b just means the username should not end with a _. And here it fails. As I said, you must replace the .*s with more restricted versions.

@WiktorStribiżew, Give me an example in https://regex101.com

Already given. And just above, too.
